# How can I plot scatter plots over a shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, scatterplot

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json
import time
import geopandas as gpd
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from shapely.geometry import LineString

borough = gpd.read_file('London_Borough_Excluding_MHW.shp')
borough = borough.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:4326'})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8)) 
ax = borough.plot()

x, y = ax(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values)
ax.scatter(x,y, marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, zorder=5, s=2)
plt.show
```

This is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-5f23b6559223> in <module>
     12 ax = borough.plot()
     13 
---> 14 x, y = ax(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values)
     15 ax.scatter(x,y, marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, zorder=5, s=2)
     16 plt.show

TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not callable
```

and this is the result I got:

[image: Graph]

Comment: Please put the error message in plain text instead of an image. This makes it searchable.

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `ax` and keep the line like this: `x, y = df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values` ?

Comment: Thank you @MarceloVilla it worked! but now the points are very small. Could you tell me how to increase the size of my plot? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `plot()` method returns an `AxesSubplot` object which you are storing as `ax`. This object has various methods and properties (as you figured out by calling `ax.scatter()`) but is is not callable itself; this means you can't run `ax()`. To get the `x` and `y` coordinates, remove that call from the following line:

```
x, y = ax(df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values)
```

so it becomes:

```
x, y = df2['lon'].values, df2['lat'].values
```

This way you'll end up with an array of longitude coordinates (`x`) and an array of latitude coordinates (`y`).

Regarding the size of your points, it is controlled by the `s` parameter in the `scatter` function. You can play around with this value until you are comfortable with the size of the points. For example:

```
ax.scatter(x, y, marker="*", color='r', alpha=0.7, zorder=5, s=10)
```